# VB.NET pointer to a pointer to C

Tags: c++, vb.net, pointers

I have a C++ function:

```
MYDLL_API int scanfile(HANDLE handle, const char *filename, const char **virname){
*virname="virusA";
}
```

The parameter **virname I believe is a pointer to a pointer. Now I have the declaration of the function in VB.NET which will call this function, expecting the virname to be modified by the C++ function.

```
DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Public Shared Function scanfile(ByVal handle As Integer, ByVal strpath As String, ByRef virname2 As String) As Integer
    End Function
```

Am I calling the DLL wrong?

Comment: It is a pointer to a string.  These kind of functions are very difficult to use safely in C++, it doesn't get better when you pinvoke.  As long as you don't have to release the memory for the string, you can declare it ByRef virname2 As IntPtr and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to recover the string.

Comment: Isn't the parameter char ** a array of characters, no IntPtr?

Comment: A char* is a pointer to an array of characters.  That's how C stores a string, it doesn't have a dedicated string type.  A char** is a pointer to a pointer to such an array.  Thus a pointer to a C string.  An IntPtr can store a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'virname' is an array of C-strings (*virname = "virusA" just sets the first string - it's equivalent to virname[0] = "virusA"), so you should use the following for the last parameter:

```
ByVal virname() As String
```

Comment: No, it is not an array of strings.

Comment: No.  Pay attention to the C code, it is not assigning an array element.  The type of the string literal is char*.

Comment: You're right - it can be maddening that one can't determine the nature of an object in C++ from the declaration alone, without examining the code using the object (unlike other languages).